# Comparing two pixels and setting a texture to black depending on outcome

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to compare two pixels of the same texture and then if they are different (For Unity BTW), then for it to take the X and Y and plug that into another texture to set the pixel. My first thought was this simple script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MapDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Texture2D provinceMap;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject mapObject;

    Color borderColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);

    private void Awake()
    {

        int provinceMapSizeX = provinceMap.width;
        int provinceMapSizeY = provinceMap.height;

        Texture2D mapDisplayBorders = new Texture2D(provinceMapSizeX, provinceMapSizeY);

        for (int x = 0; x < provinceMapSizeX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < provinceMapSizeY; y++)
            {
                Color previousPixel = provinceMap.GetPixel(x - 1, y - 1);
                Color currentPixel = provinceMap.GetPixel(x, y);

                if (previousPixel != currentPixel)
                {
                    mapDisplayBorders.SetPixel(x - 1, y - 1, borderColor);
                }
            }
        }

        mapObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = mapDisplayBorders;

    }

}
```

And at first I thought this would work, and on pressing play, the plane turned darker but nothing else. then I tried messing with `borderColor` (Hence 255), but nothing happened. The `Texture2D provinceMap` is a simple image that is 64x64 pixels, about half white and half black. I am trying to get it to add a pixel of black for every color change in this example (Its supposed to be on both pixels which can be fixed in one line of code but trying to test this right now). I don't understand why this wouldn't work though. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all some general notes

- For being able to use `GetPixel` or `GetPixels` at all your source texture needs to be set to `Read/Write enabled` in the [Texture Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)
- [`Color`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) uses **float** values between `0` and `1`. If you want to use RGB values in bytes between `0` and `255` rather use [`Color32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html) instead.

  In your case it doesn't matter of course since the value will just get clamped to `1` but something you should have in mind.
- Your current value will not be **Black** but rather **Red**. If you wanted black it should rather be

  ```
  Color borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
  ```
- Using `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` repeatedly is slow!

  Rather use [`GetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels.html) and [`SetPixels`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels.html) in order to access/write all pixels in one go.
- However - and this brings us back to `Color32` - using [`GetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html) and [`SetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html) is again faster than `GetPixels` and `SetPixels` and uses less memory since it doesn't have to do the calculating between byte and float of course which brings some overhead.

  So I would rather go with `Color32` in your case.
- Then you are iterating the X and Y coordinates starting both with `0` but then you try to access `x - 1` and `y - 1` which are out of bounds coordinates!

  You would probably rather start with `x = 1` and `y = 1` in order to avoid that.
- And finally either way you have to also call [`Apply`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.Apply.html) once you are done

  > Actually apply all previous SetPixel and SetPixels changes.

So you should rather do something like e.g.

```
// Use a Color32 instead with all bytes 0 for black
Color32 borderColor = new Color32(0, 0, 0);

...

var mapDisplayBorders = new Texture2D(provinceMapSizeX, provinceMapSizeY);

// Get the entire arrays of pixels at once for both textures
var borderPixels = mapDisplayBorders.GetPixels32();
var mapPixels = provinceMap.GetPixels32();

// Start iterating from 1 to prevent out of bounds coordinates
for (int x = 1; x < provinceMapSizeX; x++)
{
    for (int 1 = 0; y < provinceMapSizeY; y++)
    {
        // The pixels in the array are laid out row by row
        var previousPixel = mapPixels[(x - 1) + (y - 1) * provinceMapSizeX];
        var currentPixel = mapPixels[x + y * provinceMapSizeX];

        if (AreEqual(previousPixel, currentPixel))
        {
            borderPixels[(x - 1) + (y - 1) * provinceMapSizeX] = borderColor;
        }
    }
}

mapDisplayBorders.SetPixels32(borderPixels);
mapDisplayBorders.Apply();

mapObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = mapDisplayBorders;

...

// Afaik this is not implemented for some reason so have to do it ourselves
private bool AreEqual(Color32 a, Color32 b)
{
    return a.r == b.r && a.g == b.g && a.b == b.b && a.a == b.a;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting, but I had said that I set it to 255 so it would be red. Thanks though with the Color32, I didn't know that was 255 and I much prefer that. (Rather annoyingly I cannot space paragraphs put on phone so sorry for the mess of text) if I can read correctly, in the code you are having it see if its equal, and if it is, set the pixel(s) of the same color to black, which I will need later,  but in this case I do need it to be outlined which I can fix with a bit of a tweak I think. Then again I could be wrong. Either way thanks for the help!

Comment: @Endergaming2546 well your title is `Comparing two pixels and setting a texture to black depending on outcome` ... and your code is also comparing and setting the color ... so no, this won't be an outline but rather do what you asked and implemented ;)

Comment: Oh. Yeah sorry didn't realize that was the title! Thanks though, I appreciate it.